# "arrow function expected no return value" with clean-up function in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, use-effect

Here is my `useEffect` with a simple clean-up function `() => { inbox?.destroy(); }`, but it raises a warning when I let the clean-up function there. Why is that, isn't the clean-up function a legit syntax? How to fix it (*of course without removing the clean-up function*)?

[image]

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { currentUser } = initialState!;
    let inbox: Talk.Inbox;
    if (!currentUser || !talkjsContainerRef.current) return;

    Talk.ready.then(async () => {
      const me = employeeToUser(currentUser);
      window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({ appId, me });
      if (id === undefined) {
        // me without other => most recent message first
        inbox = window.talkSession.createInbox();
      } else {
        // me with an other => select other
        const other = employeeToUser(await readEmployee(Number(id)));
        const conversation = window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other));
        conversation.setParticipant(me);
        conversation.setParticipant(other);
        inbox = window.talkSession.createInbox({ selected: conversation });
      }
      inbox.mount(talkjsContainerRef.current);
    });

    return () => {
      inbox?.destroy();
    };
  }, [id, initialState]);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've captured the error message on the screenshot, it's from VSCode, I didn't write it up.

Comment: I thought you added that (like the box around it). Wow that's bad phrasing on ESLint's part.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**A possible fix:** turn `return;` to `return undefined;`

[image]

#### Explanation:

I had violated the [`consistent-return` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)

> This rule requires `return` statements to **either always or never** specify values

At line 4, `if (!currentUser || !talkjsContainerRef.current) return;`, my `return` statement **didn't specify a value**, which is **contradictory to my "clean-up function"**.